# Nexus repository path

Tags: jenkins, nexus

I have uploaded some release artifacts from Jenkins to Nexus. I can see they have been created under Nexus as per the -Dversion I have provided.

Example: AppName-BuildNumber-Snapshot.zip

However, somehow the repository path is autogenerated, it has extra yyyymmdd.hhmmss appended to it.

Example: AppName-BuildNumber-Snapshot-yyyymmdd.hhmmss.zip

I would like to download the release artifact from Jenkins but due to the autogenerated Nexus repository path I am not able to download it in the separate job.

How can I force it to stop adding yyyymmdd.hhmmss to the repository path? Or is there anyway I can retrieve the repository path using AppName and BuildNumber?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are uploading a SNAPSHOT, then Nexus dynamically stores it with a timestamp. That's because you can replace -SNAPSHOTs with newer copy w/same GAV. This is unlike real # jars which cannot/should not be redeployed, thus preserving their integrity.

To download a -SNAPSHOT, you just reference it as -SNAPSHOT; maven, aether, etc will retrieve the latest.

Maven (by default) only checks the [remote repository](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories) for versions newer than your local once daily, unless you use -U option or change the updatePolicy.

If you want "solid" number, then you must [release](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/index.html)  jar.

btw, you should see it's -yyyymmdd.hhmmss-nn, where nn is an incremental number for that version.

---

Nexus supports [many different repository formats](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager2/concepts/the-basics---components%2C-repositories-and-repository-formats). If you only require maven, [use Nexus 2](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager2/concepts/the-basics---components%2C-repositories-and-repository-formats) as it better supports maven.
Repository types: Maven has [two distinct types](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager2/concepts/an-example---maven-repository-format):[Release and Snapshot Repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#What_is_a_SNAPSHOT_version).

If you want to "*upload a zip file containing release artifacts and retrieve it back based on the build version number?*", then that's what you should do.

You must [configure a repository of type release](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager2/maven-and-other-build-tools/adding-a-new-repository), not snapshots (gleened from: `-DrepositoryId=dsnexus-snapshots`) (or in addition to type snapshots).
To pass the "build version number", then presumably, you have:

```
[ X ] Create a formatted version number
Environment Variable Name [ label ]
```

Make sure your maven step has:

```
[ X ] Inject build variables
```

Then, `mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.my.gid -DartifactId=AppName -Dversion=${label} -DrepositoryId=dsnexus-release`

ps: you'll also want to implement a [cleanup strategy](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager2/configuration/managing-scheduled-tasks) in your Nexus repository if you are pumping every build as a new artifact.

Comment: Thanks Ian for the detailed answer. Can I please check if there are any alternative option for storing release artifacts instead using SNAPSHOT? All we need to do is upload a zip file containing release artifacts (.dll, .exe, .config) and retrieve it back based on the build version number? Also, do you have a jenkins command to download release artifacts? I am using the following command to upload it to nexus: mvn deploy:deploy-file -X -DgroupId= -DartifactId= -Dversion= -Dpackaging=zip -Dfile= -DrepositoryId=dsnexus-snapshots -Durl= -DgeneratePom=true